# aligned equations with text in list

Tags: equations, alignment

[image]

on an exercise, I use `enumerate` to write my answers to questions a) / b) / c) but I did not figure out how to perfectly aligned the answers on c). I did not find how to align the equation *GS = ...* with the one below *MF = ...* . Do I have to make like a box for aligning the equal symbols ?

here is my code :

````
%mathématiques - fichier numérique de tous mes exercices
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %pour le symbole n°
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true} % pour les listes avec \enumitem : à inclure si on utilise 
\usepackage{enumitem}

% spécification des marges, taille papier
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\geometry{hscale=0.85,vscale=0.85,centering}
%\usepackage{fullpage} % une autre solution, pas testée

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{} 
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\raggedright\mbox{\frakfamily\fraklines\yinipar{S}}}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
% fin de la définition des marges

\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

% le package qui pemet de définir des unités et leur affichage
\usepackage{siunitx} % Alignement des valeurs etc.
\sisetup{
    round-mode          = places, % Rounds numbers
    round-precision     = 2, % to 2 places
}

\usepackage{xcolor} % pour les couleurs sur les règles graduées par exemple
\definecolor{shamrockgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.62, 0.38}
\definecolor{rose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.0, 0.5}
\definecolor{richlavender}{rgb}{0.67, 0.38, 0.8}
\definecolor{tangelo}{rgb}{0.98, 0.3, 0.0}

%----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\noindent MATH\'EMATIQUES
\newline
\vspace{1cm}
\noindent\begin{cursive}Un exemple de repère:\end{cursive}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node {$\bullet$};
        \draw (0,0) node[below left]{$O$};
        \draw[->] (-0.4,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[dashed] (-1.1,0) -- (-0.4,0);
        \draw (1,0) node[below]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-0.4) -- (0,1);
        \draw[dashed] (0,-0.8)-- (0,-0.4);
        \draw (0,1) node[left]{$y$};
        \draw [dashed] (1,0) -- (2.4,0);
        \draw [dashed] (0,1) -- (0,2.4);
        \draw [dashed] (2,2) -- (2,0) node[below] {$2$};
        \draw [dashed] (2,2) -- (0,2) node[left] {$2$};
        \fill [red] (2,2) node[above=2mm,right]{$\alpha(2,2)$} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}

%les exercices
\newpage

\noindent\begin{cursive}Exercice \no 9 p176:\end{cursive}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]  
        \draw[->] [thick] (-5.5,0) -- (3.5,0);
        \draw (-5,0) node [below=5pt]{$-5\phantom{-}$};
        \draw (-4,0) node [below=5pt]{$-4\phantom{-}$};
        \draw (-3,0) node [below=5pt]{$-3\phantom{-}$}; 
        \draw (-2,0) node [below=5pt]{$-2\phantom{-}$};     
        \draw (-1,0) node [below=5pt]{$-1\phantom{-}$};
        \draw (0,0) node [below=5pt, red]{$0$};
        \node at (0,0) {$|$};
        \draw (1,0) node [below=5pt]{$1$};
        \draw (2,0) node [below=5pt]{$2$};      
        \node at (2,0) {$|$};
        \draw (3,0) node [below=5pt]{$3$};  
        \node at (3,0) {$|$};
%le point F(-5,0)
        \draw (-5,0) node[above=5pt, rose]{$F$};
        \fill[rose] (-5,0) node{$\times$};
%le point G(-4,0)
        \draw (-4,0) node[above=5pt, shamrockgreen]{$G$};
        \fill[shamrockgreen] (-4,0) node{$\times$};
%le point O(-3,0)
        \draw (-3,0) node[above=5pt, richlavender]{$O$};
        \fill[richlavender] (-3,0) node{$\times$};
%le point I(-2,0)
        \draw (-2,0) node[above=5pt, red]{$I$};
        \fill[red] (-2,0) node{$\times$};
%le point M(-1,0)
        \draw (-1,0) node[above=5pt, tangelo]{$M$};
        \fill[tangelo] (-1,0) node{$\times$};
%le point S(1,0)
        \draw (1,0) node[above=5pt, blue]{$S$};
        \fill[blue] (1,0) node{$\times$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]

\item $OF = IG = OM = MS = 2$

\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
    &OI &=1 \\
    &OM &=2 \\
    &GS &=5 \\
    &MG &=3
\end{aligned}$

\item calcul des distances $GS$ et $MF$
\newline
$OM = MS$ donc $GS = GM + OM = GM + MS$
\newline
$OM = OF$ donc $MF = MO + OF = 2.MO$
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}```
````

Comment: Unrelated to the issue itself: The dot between "2" and "MO"  seems to be a multiplication sign. For a vertically centered dot with improved spacing around it, you might want to use `\cdot` instead.

Comment: Another unrelated: comment: do you that, with the `T1` font encoding, and`utf8` input encoding (which, by the way, is now the default), you can type in your source code `MATHÉMATIQUES`?

Comment: thank you both for the unrelated comments, i update all my lines with your useful tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an `aligned` environment and the `\text` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %pour le symbole n°
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true} % pour les listes avec \enumitem : à inclure si on utilise 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]

\item calcul des distances $GS$ et $MF$

$\begin{aligned}[t]
OM &= MS &\text{donc} &&GS &= GM + OM = GM + MS\\
OM &= OF &\text{donc} &&MF &= MO + OF = 2.MO
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ok. i will try to do the same on the last equals too, i did not see that are not aligned too ( ... = GM + MS ) and also ( ... = 2.MO ) / thanks for your help.